# Massive delay in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On one page I see a 500ms delay on some AJAX requests which I cannot explain. The page in question fires two AJAX requests to the same action on load and one of them will be blocked. Why is that?

What does the ASP.NET stack do before the `Application_AcquireRequestState` method is called? I have used the ghetto profiling method of MiniProfiler and when `Application_AcquireRequestState`  is called I can see a long time is spent between the calls to those two `Application_PostMapRequestHandler` and `Application_AcquireRequestState`.

I have disabled the session state entirely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Appfail.WebForms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AttributeRouting" version="2.5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AttributeRouting.Core" version="2.5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AttributeRouting.Core.Web" version="2.5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="2.1.267" />
  <package id="CodeContracts.Unofficial" version="1.0.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DataAnnotationsExtensions" version="1.1.0.0" />
  <package id="DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3" version="1.1.0.0" />
  <package id="DiffPlex" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.1.0.12182" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" version="4.1.0.12182" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core" version="4.1.0.12182" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client" version="0.25.0-draft1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientAuthorization" version="0.25.0-draft1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Core" version="0.25.0-draft1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core" version="4.1.0.12182" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" version="4.1.0.12182" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DynamicQuery" version="1.0" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="LinqKit" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <package id="MiniProfiler" version="2.0.2" />
  <package id="MiniProfiler.EF" version="2.0.3" />
  <package id="morelinq" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RequestReduce" version="1.8.76" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivator" version="1.5.1" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: ive never seen this *ever*.  What modules are you running and what work do you do between the two?

Comment: @AndrasZoltan I don't do ANYTHING between the two that I know of. I have added packages.config to the question.

Comment: I would think that at least one of these packages is causing the delay as out of the box MVC even using EF or LINQ does not cause these issues that anyone is aware of.  I cannot answer this as I am not familiar with all of these packages.  Have you upgraded/added any packages before this started?  Could it be a temp ASP.NET file issue (having trouble finding the right assemblies)?

Comment: @Tommy, not that I know of. I found the issue locally, it was my Redis session state provider, but on AppHarbor it happens with the default in-memory one as well.

Comment: The ASP.NET session state is not the culprit, I have disabled it completely and the delay still occurs.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed after upgrading to .NET 4.5 and MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe unrelated, bu I had the same problem because of lots of initializations I did in Global.asax Application_Start() method. Once I minimized them my first cold load became much faster than before.

Comment: I don't have too many initializations. However, I still have the delay between requests. I have a page that fires two AJAX requests on load and one of them will be blocked for half a second.